# H2O2 Storage and Package

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to keep a medical-grade 3% H2O2 solution in a glass vial as the container for medicinal applications. It was claimed that inside of the vial should be covered with a thin layer of silicone to prevent H2O2 decomposition. Is there any need for this?

Comment: I have never seen a requirement like coating the inner surface of the glass bottle with silicone before. Hydrogen peroxide doesn't react with glass, but is prone to decomposition being exposed to the light, so switching to the amber glass might be a good idea. Out of curiosity, what is your source of information?

Comment: You may find more of a difference with stabilized H2O2 (e.g. addition of phosphates or stannates) than with a silicone layer. See http://www.h2o2.com/faqs/FaqDetail.aspx?fId=11 . Many over-the-counter brands of H2O2 contain  stabilizers... which might or might noit affect your use.